# How to save kinetic data to image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kineticjs

I am using Kinetic.js to create a dynamic image with random shapes. This works fine.

Later, I want to save that data generated to a image file in a way similar to this `img = canvas.toDataURL()`.

I tried to do:

```
var image
stage.toDataURL({
callback: function(dataUrl) {
kineticdataURL = dataUrl;
image=dataURL.toDataURL or  image =kineticdataURL

}
});
window.open(image);
```

All that I get is a blank screen.

Answer (score 0):

set `x,y,width,height` properties.